# Largest size for randomness extractor

Tags: randomness, it.information-theory, pseudorandomness

Suppose we have a source $X$ with min-entropy $\ell$. A *randomness extractor* is defined as a function $f$ which satisfies the total variation $||f(X, R)-U_M||_{TV}\leq \epsilon$ where $R$ is an external randomness and $U_M$ is a uniform random variable over a set of $M$ points.

> What is the largest value of $M$ for which such an  extractor
>   $f$ for source $X$ exists ?

Is there any connection between randomness extractor and the following problem:

> Given two dependent random variables $X$ and $Y$, how many bits we can
>   extract from $Y$ that are  almost independent from $X$ (where the
>   independence is measured via total variational distance) ?

Thanks

Comment: In general, 0. If $X$ is identical to $Y$, then there's no deterministic extraction procedure that will produce uncorrelated random bits relative to $X$. If you use a seed $S$ of length $d$, then you will get at most $d$ bits that are independent of $X$ (namely, simply output the seed). Thus you'll need some assumption on the dependence of $X$ on $Y$ to get a non-trivial statement.

Comment: suppose there's some nontrivial upper bound on $I(X;Y)$ in terms of $\min(H(X), H(Y))$?

Comment: @HenryYuen, Thanks for the comment, but could you please explain what kind of assumption of the dependence of $X$ and $Y$? to be honest what I want is exactly the conditions that we might impose on $X$ and $Y$ such that the length of extracted bits is maximum, particularly the connection of this with maximal correlation or common information.

Comment: @SureshVenkat I dont understand your comment, are you asking something?

Comment: I was suggesting a way to encode dependence of X and Y

Comment: I think I could find a bound for this. Leftover hash lemma asserts the existence of a randomness extractor for random variable $X$ with  length close to the min entropy of $X$. We can hence say that  $M<H_{\infty}(X)$.